# iOS fixed size views displaying different widths and heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, graphics, uikit

So I have some one line views that are set to be dividers between fields.  They are UIViews that I just set the background color on.  All of them are in IB with constraints, the width or height set to 1, and then tied to other fields and/or the leading/trialing space to the superview.

The view size for he VC is inferred, and is at the 4 inch size.

But when viewed on a 6 device, or in the simulator, these single point views sometimes come out as what appears to be 2 points.  I've tried raising the compression resistance of the views, as well as tying them to items that don't require them to expand if it's needed to display the view while keeping to the constraints.

The top, middle and bottom lines, as well as the two vertical ones are all 1 point width or height views.

What is causing these views to display like this?

[image]

Comment: Rendering errors like this can occur when frame origins are on decimal values. Try debugging while running to see if the frames are whole values or not.

Comment: tried that, not it.  the frame values are all showing whole numbers.

Comment: Problem was they were not on an even X or Y value, (vertical or horizontal views).  I didn't think that was an issue, only views that began on origins with decimal values.  Chalk another one up...

Comment: So it was that the frame origins were decimal values? Sorry confused by your two comments.

Comment: no, one of the origin values, don't remember if it was x or y, was an odd number.  moved things around so that both x and y were even values, and the problem went away.